# WooCommerce Use Pricing Tables as Product Variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm attempting to emergency-revamp my print company's website after the guy "developing" the site for me simply disappeared off the face of the planet last week, leaving me with no site and potentially countless thousands in lost revenue (not happy isn't close). All goes well until I came across this issue and for the life of me I can't find *any* answer's *anywhere* to it:

Creating a tabbed table containing sizes and prices in Wordpress... easy 
(this is not a stereotypical pricing table)

Integrate woocommerce into the chosen theme...easy

Now, making each price an individual "add to cart" button - major rage quit imminent.

I have no interest in making a product for every single conceivable variation as it's simply not necessary should I be able to get the tabbed table working as described. Having to do so would probably give me heart failure as I would then have to create yet more un-necessary graphics. My customers just want to be able to see the price, click the price (and thus "add it to cart"), purchase, done.

Here's the tabbed table in question in case everything I've just type makes zero sense: http://www.protradeprinting.com/canvasprints/

ANY suggestions would be a big help.

Comment: I would respectfully recommend hiring an experienced WordPress developer, and signing a good contract. As it has been written, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Send me a private message and I can help you get straightened out.

Comment: This is a neat use case and I'm intrigued, but agree with mevius that as is, it is too broad for SO. I'm sure you aren't too keen on developers at the moment, but I might be able to work on it later in the week if you wanted to get in touch to hammer out scope, etc.

Comment: FYI, from what I've seen here, @helgatheviking knows her stuff, and has the reputation to prove it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the kind words @mevius!